# Emulator Error when launching AVD in Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem when I am trying to launch my AVD on Android Studio 3.0.
I have installed HAXM to run this AVD. The RAM allocated to run the HAXM is 2GiB.

```
Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'
Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio input failed
Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'    
Emulator: [7752]:WARNING:android/android-emu/android/base/async/AsyncSocketServer.cpp:99:Error when accepting host connectionError message: Unknown error
```

My AVD is a Nexus 5 API 23, CPU/ABI is x86. RAM is 512MB, VM Heap is 128 MB, and Graphics is Software - GLES 2.0. My PC's RAM is 5GB.

Comment: There is Virtual Hardware UEFI BIOS Setting. Which is by default off, You need to enable them First. Then your Emulator will run.

Comment: Are you talking about the VT-x and VT-d? If so, I have already enabled these two before creating the AVD.

Answer (score 0):

look in Android\android-sdk folder if it doesn't  have the Platform-Tools folder containing the adb.exe

download platform tools again and deleted the previous one and  extract the new one and see if it work

Comment: Hi, I did what you suggested but the errors still persist. Does the model of my Graphics card / Processor card of my PC have something to do with the errors? My Graphics card is Intel (R) Q45/Q43 Express Chipset and my processor is Intel(R) Core(TM) 2 Duo CPU E8500 @ 3.16GHz (2 CPUs), (~3.2GHz)

Comment: when you created  the emular which type did you choose ?
try this when you create a new device at Graphics : Software :GLES 2.0

Comment: i did select Software:GLES 2.0 when I created the new device